# Receiving the message error "{" immediately follows a field part---line"

Tags: bibtex, errors, urlbst

I use bibtex and my bib file looks like

```
@article{Bohm,
  title = {Discussion of Experimental Proof for the Paradox of Einstein, Rosen, and Podolsky},
  author = {Bohm, D. and Aharonov, Y.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume = {108},
  issue = {4},
  pages = {1070--1076},
  year = {1957},
  month = {Nov},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.108.1070},
  note = {\url{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.108.1070}},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}

@article{Cerf,
  title = {Simulating Maximal Quantum Entanglement without Communication},
  author = {Cerf, N. J. and Gisin, N. and Massar, S. and Popescu, S.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {94},
  issue = {22},
  pages = {2204031--2204034},
  year = {2005},
  month = {Jun},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.220403},
  note = {\url{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.220403}},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
```

The problem is that when I compile my bib file, I get

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)

> The top-level auxiliary file: title.aux

> The style file: unsrt.bst

> Database file #1: title.bib

> "{" immediately follows a field part---line 28 of file title.bib  :
> note =   :
> {\url{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.220403}}

> I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry (There was 1 error message)

And this error is always for the `Cerf` reference (the second I gave you)... Since I have lots of these references (like `Bohm`) that look all the same to me, I don't understand why I get this error nor how to solution it...

**Edit** : here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,          
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},        
    linktocpage
}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\section{The EPR-paradox}
I cite this \cite{Bohm} and that \cite{Cerf}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{title}

\end{document}
```

Where the title.bib is the bib file given above.

**Edit from zaturalma2:**
Old question and was closed  so I could not provide an answer, but I had the same problem today on Overleaf when editing my .bib file. The solution was to remove the extra spaces around the = signs. So try it like this:

@article{Cerf,

```
  title={Simulating Maximal Quantum Entanglement without Communication},

  author={Cerf, N. J. and Gisin, N. and Massar, S. and Popescu, S.},

  journal={Phys. Rev. Lett.},

  volume={94},

  issue={22},

  pages={2204031--2204034},

  year={2005},

  month={Jun},

  doi={10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.220403},

  note={\url{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.220403}},

  publisher={American Physical Society}
}
```

Comment: Please add a complete minimal working example.

Comment: That is strange. I have successfully compiled after including all your .bib entries by using a `\nocite` command. I did not get a single error for `\bibliographystyle` acm, ieeetr or plain. Please post an MWE as asked by @MarcoDaniel above.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, a MWE has been edited

Comment: @MMA, the MWE gives me the same error

Comment: Sorry, but the MWE doesn't show any error on my system

Comment: @mwoua Same here, no error in my system. You can find the relevant files [here](https://sites.google.com/site/stackexchangefilesforothers/), please look under the relevant folder. The only thing you can do, 1) Change the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to something else, just to check your .bst file, 2a) If you do not receive any error, get a fresh copy of unsrt.bst, 2b) If that fails, re-install bibtex. Do not know what else to suggest.

Comment: That's very weird...